# Assign Future<String> to String variable inside FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this Stateless Widge and I am trying to dynamically get the driving distance from the users location to a predefined location and want to display the distance as a string. I have a Future request within a FutureBuilder. When I assign it to final this way I get Instance of Future. I have scoured the internet and yet to have found any thing with nested Future within a FutureBuilder. Is there a way to do this? Do I need to generate another async/await method to call and assign this future string?

I commented in the FutureBuilder where I want to assign the string value and the Future method call is below the FutureBuilder

Thanks in advance

```
class LocationInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final getLoc;
  LocationInput({Key? key, required this.getLoc}) : super(key: key);
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

  double _distInMeters = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var userLocation = determinePosition();
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: userLocation,
      builder: ((BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Position> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final distance = getDistance(getLoc, snapshot); // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO ASSIGN THE FUTURE<STRING> AS A STRING
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, top: 12.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                getDirections(getLoc.latitude, getLoc.longitude);
              },
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.directions)],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("$distance mi"),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text("An error has occurred please try again."),
          );
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.directions))
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Text(""),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}

Future<String> getLocDistance(getLoc, snapshot) async {
  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
  PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
    googleMapsApi,
    PointLatLng(getLoc.latitude, getLoc.longitude),
    PointLatLng(snapshot.data!.latitude, snapshot.data!.longitude),
    travelMode: TravelMode.driving,
  );

  if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
    result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
      polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
    });
  } else {
    print(result.errorMessage);
  }

  //polulineCoordinates is the List of longitute and latidtude.
  double totalDistance = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
    totalDistance += calculateDistance(
        polylineCoordinates[i].latitude,
        polylineCoordinates[i].longitude,
        polylineCoordinates[i + 1].latitude,
        polylineCoordinates[i + 1].longitude);
  }
  return ((totalDistance * 1000) / 1609.344).toStringAsFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: `future builder` it self is a `stateful widge`t, why not run this async function in `initstate`, use `Future.then()` to update your state after you get the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the comments provided to me. I found resources eventually that putting together made more sense about futures. Here is what I ended up doing.

I converted the widget to stateful and created a reference to the future function in the state.

```
  var getDirectionsInMiles;
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getDirectionsInMiles = getMeterDirections(widget.getLoc);
  }
```

Then getting the userLocation in the getMeterDirections kept it so there was only 1 future being called in the future builder. It is not good practice to pass variables through the futurebuilder future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do,

Instead of having `userlocation` as the future of FutureBuilder

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: userLocation,
```

You can just use `getLocDistance` as the future.

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: getLocDistance(getLoc),
```

and then update your `getLocDistance` as follows:

```
Future<String> getLocDistance(getLoc) async {
  final latlng = await userLocation();
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
  PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
   googleMapsApi,
   PointLatLng(getLoc.latitude, getLoc.longitude),
   PointLatLng(latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude),
   travelMode: TravelMode.driving,
  );
// rest of the code
}
```

and you will directly get `distance` in your builder.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final distance = snapshot.data!;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying let me clear something up, my getLoc param I'm passing is the devices current latlang position, so when it gets passed to getLocDistance that's what the first poly points are and the snapshot.data is getting the fixed latlang of where they need to go to, so I need data from the snapshot to figure out the distance does that help clarify what it is doing?